# How to show a string as a hyperlink dynamically?

Tags: asp.net

Let's consider that I have a comma separated string. For example, "APL-1,APL-2,APL-3,APL-4".

So I want to show each one string with hyperlink and on that it should redirect to some other page.

Note: The comma separated string may vary (means may increase or decrease)

So please guide me how to do this?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am unable to show this comma separated string with hyperlink of each string with comma separated..

Comment: Yes, but where are you stuck? What part of the process is unclear? Splitting the strings? Iterating the strings? Outputting links? Generating links?

Comment: Like see I have string "APL-1,APL-2,APL-3,APL-4". I want to show each string as hyperlink to User Interface page and by clicking this it should redirect to another page with different querystring value.

Comment: You wrote that in your question. I don't want to repeat myself, but [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do its by going through each element in comma separated string and creating link using this string.

```
string links = string.Empty;
string strInput = "pAPL-1,APL-2,APL-3,APL-4";
string []arrInput = strInput.Split(',');
foreach(string str in arrInput)
   links += @"<a href=""www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?qs1=" + str + " >"+str+"</a><br />";
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But when I am clicking on link it is not going properly. Also how will show all the comma separated links on page. Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: You have to give the correct url to go it properly. Make a div assign it some id like <div id="divLinks" runat="server"></div>. In code behind get this div and assign you links string. divLinks.InnerHtml = links;

Comment: I did this, but when I am clicking on link its not working. Also out of 4 only two strings are showing as a hyperlink. Please guide me, its bit urgent.

Comment: See, I have kept debug point and checked. I am getting like     

"<a href="AccrualInfo.aspx?id=APL-1>APL-1</a><br />
<a href="AccrualInfo.aspx?id=APL-3>APL-3</a><br />
<a href="AccrualInfo.aspx?id=APL-4>APL-4</a><br />
<a href="AccrualInfo.aspx?id=APL-5>APL-5</a><br />"

So in this one " missing on each hyperlink's href end while forming links.

Comment: You are missing domain part add your website url before AccruallInfo.aspx. As in my answer I have www.Somesite.com/ for instance

Comment: Hey I did. Now its working fine. Thank you so much for your help........ 
Only bit change required that is "links += @"<a href=""www.somsite.com/somepage.aspx?qs1=" + str + "\">"+str+"</a><br />";"